# React-Navigation/drawer items bottom border

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I'm new to React native ,I have add a react navigation drawer menu to my app,but how add a border color to menu items ?
I have already do this

```
options={{
             drawerLabel: 'Page title',
             drawerIcon: () => (
              <View
                style={
               {
                        borderLeftColor: 'red',
                        borderLeftWidth: 2,
                        paddingLeft: 5,
                      }                  
                }>            
              </View>
            ),
            
            }}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

solution found by modify itemStyle in the Drawer Navigator

```
<Drawer.Navigator
    drawerContentOptions={{
      activeTintColor: '#D09900',
      itemStyle: { borderRadius:0,marginVertical: 0,borderBottomWidth:0.5,borderBottomColor:'#D09900' },
    }}>
```